# Transition doesn't work with border-image and gradient

Tags: html, css

I am using `border-image` with `gradient` and it works fine, but it seems `transition` is not supported for it.

Is it possible to achieve `transition` on hover for this example?

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/et0ffrqx/)

```css
div {
    border:10px solid blue;
    height:120px;
    float:left;
    transition:1s all;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, blue) 1 100%;
}
div:hover {
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, skyblue, blue) 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: It's still not possible the animate gradients. You can try using a pseudo-class method tho :)

Comment: Thanks @Terry I'll experiment with that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the others already told you, it isn't possible to transition a gradient (yet). The best way to fake the effect would be to work with opacity, which can be transitioned. You don't need to add any elements however, the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements will do just fine. have a look at the following css:

```
div {
    height:120px;
    width:10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: salmon;
    background-clip: content-box;
    position: relative;
}
div:after, div:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    content:'';
}
div:after {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, blue 100%);
    z-index: -1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
div:before {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, skyblue 0%, blue 100%);
    z-index: -2;
}
div:hover:after {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

And an example: https://jsfiddle.net/et0ffrqx/2/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I successfully managed using pseudo-classes as Terry suggested earlier. This is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

### Not Possible

That isn't possible yet because `linear-gradient` is calculated as an image, not actually colors.

### Solution

Try putting the `<div>` within another `<div>` which can act as a border. Then the outer `<div>` can have an animated background

I've found [this codepen](http://codepen.io/quasimondo/pen/lDdrF) demonstrating how this can be done with JavaScript.

My best bet for you would be to have two `<div>` stacked on top of each other. The bottom `<div>` would be the target gradient and the top being the start. Then just fade the top `<div>`

```css
#start {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(red,blue);
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

#end {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(green,orange);
  z-index: -1;
}

#start:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="start">Start</div>
<div id="end">End</div>
```

The snippet demonstrates a simple way to fade between gradients. Not perfect but smoother and without JavaScript. Put your other stuff in side the `<div>` and adjust the width and height to your needs.

Also try using `:before` and `:after` to avoid having duplicate `div`s

Comment: Correct, but I think you should have at least nested the elements, or even better, not added any markup at all and worked with pseudo elements. This will be a b*tch to maintain and position.

Comment: "calculated as an image" is helpful for understanding this.

Answer (score 1):

### No

Animations aren't supported for those properties.

You can however, think of another way to accomplish this visually.

maybe you have 2 wrappers around something, and they are 2 different gradients, and there is padding around them to simulate the look of a border... and then the elements with the gradients have opacity that fades to and from on hover.

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/5uoypaoo/

```
<div class="gradient-1">
    <div class="gradient-2"></div>
    <div class="thing"></div>
</div>
```

```
.thing {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    float: left;
}

.gradient-1 {
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, pink, blue);
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 1rem;
    float: left;
}

.gradient-1:hover .gradient-2 {
    opacity: 1;
}

.gradient-2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, lightgreen, orange);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```